# load linux screen setups from file to setup a series of screens to run different categories of commands

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

I use linux screen heavily , generally if the OS didn't restart or say as long as the SCREEN process is there, I can re-attach to my terminals. 
But I don't want to set-up the screens each time after my computer restarts that's tedious work.

so I generally setup a series of screens to run different categories of command
1. create a window, rename the screen, run specific command
2. etc...

Is there a way to create these screen setups automatically , say can I script to do that ?

**Edit**: what is more important here is how to paste some command into the window after the window is created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, of course.

You just need to specify the configuration of screen in `~/.screenrc`.
If you want to use several configurations, you can create several config files
and start screens with `-c` key.

```
screen -c ~/.screenrc1
screen -c ~/.screenrc2
screen -c ~/.screenrc3
```

Example of `~/.screenrc`:

```
screen -t news 8 newsbeuter
screen -t jabber 9 freetalk
```

here will be open two windows: on 8 -- `newsbeuter` (the name of the window `news`); on 9 — `freetalk` (the name of the window `jabber`).

Comment: what about execute commands after create window ? just put commands right after the create window command ?

Comment: which commands do you mean? Can you please provide an example?

Comment: I mean after **screen -t news 8 newsbeuter** I want to execute a series of load up commands like: **. initalias1** right in that window

Comment: you mean you want to send some strings in that window?

Comment: It's not so easy but you can play with `readbuf p /etc/passwd` and `paste p` commands. The idea is copy some file into an internal register of screen and then paste this register into the screen.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13141/discussion-between-zinking-and-igor-chubin)